# Check a condition and also identify the pattern in url through Regex in Zend

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

i am implementing the Zend Regex Routing, and i have to perform multiple checks for the url. For example, if this is my url:

**http://localhost/application/public/index.php/module/controller/action**

and this is my regex condition in my bootstrap file, which matches when the url does not contain "login":

```
$router->addRoute('ui', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    '^((?!login/).)*$',
    array(
        'module'     => 'mod1',
        'controller' => 'cont1',
        'action'     => 'action1'
    ),
    array( )
));
```

Now i also want to identify the pattern: `([^-]*)/([^-]*)/([^-]*)` from the url for knowing the module, controller and action, so that i can route to it.

How can it be achieved ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know absoluely nothing about Zend, but the regex:

```
^(?=(?:(?!login/).)*$).*?/([^-/]*)/([^-/]*)/([^-/]*)/?$
```

matches:

```
entire match: "http://localhost/application/public/index.php/module/controller/action", from 0 to 70
- group(1) = "module"
- group(2) = "controller"
- group(3) = "action"
```

on the input:

```
http://localhost/application/public/index.php/module/controller/action
```

The part `(?=((?!login/).)*$)` makes sure there is no `login/` in the string, and `([^-/]*)/([^-/]*)/([^-/]*)/?$` grabs the last three `.../` before the end of the input (`$`).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. However i cant identify the appropriate module, controller and action, if i dont specify them in the url. Hence i am using this hack in my bootstrap file: **$front->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', true);** Now if a request cant be dispatched, it will route to the default module controller (I have specified a default module in my config file :)